# latex special character ∟

Tags: symbols

I'm looking for a way to insert this symbol ∟ (html: ∟) in my document. I found some posts in the internet referring to \usepackage{mathdesign} and \rightangle, but this seems to be this char: >
has anybody an idea? 
thank you very much!

Comment: Have you tried to do anything or researched it yourself? What are you having problems with? We won't write your code for you, but we'll be willing to help out if you narrow down the issue.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](http://goo.gl/z69vm) Your post was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution with picture mode:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pict2e}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\rightangle}{%
  \begingroup\setlength{\unitlength}{1ex}%
  \begin{picture}(1.2,1)
  \roundcap
  \polyline(0.1,1)(0.1,0)(1.1,0)
  \end{picture}%
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}

Here is the right angle symbol \rightangle{} in context.

\Large

And \rightangle{} changes size

\end{document}
```

[image]

A solution with the STIX fonts. This variant can be used in math mode and automatically changes size in subscripts or superscripts.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareFontEncoding{LS1}{}{}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{LS1}{stix}{m}{n}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\rightangle}{%
  \text{\usefont{LS1}{stix}{m}{n}\symbol{"D9}}%
}

\begin{document}

Here is the right angle symbol \rightangle{} in context.

\Large

And \rightangle{} changes size

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you! this was exactly what I was looking for. Solved! :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried 
    \usepackage{graphicx}

```
\rotatebox[origin=c]{180}{$\neg$}
```

The vertical piece is a bit smaller but it might work.

Comment: thanks, this a great advice. It will do for now. I was looking yesterday for a package to use the character, but was not able to find a way to do so..